# Performing computations from two tables through, selecting a column value based on a another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I got two different tables df_postErup & df_preErup. I want to obtain a value for a certain month from the df_postErup and then deduct the corresponding mean value form df_preErup. (i.e for month = 3 get value 0.394 from df_postErup, then obtain the mean_value = 0.669 for that month = 3 from df_preErup. Then calculate the difference and store it in a new column called 'delta' 0.394-0.669)

I have written the following code but its giving me Nan values,

```
for i in range (1,13):
df_postErup['delta'] = (df_postErup.loc[df_postErup['months'] == i, 'values']) - (df_preErup.loc[df_preErup['months'] == i, 'mean_values'])
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem, but if anyone has a better answer, pls do post

```
 #Create a New empty column in df_postErup which will store the mean values for each month from df_pre

df_postErup['mean ndvi pre'] = ""
for i in range(0,12):
df_postErup.loc[df_postErup['months'] == (i + 1), ['mean ndvi pre']] = df_preErup.iloc[i,1]

#Calculate the difference, delta
df_postErup['delta'] = df_postErup['ndvi'] - df_postErup['mean ndvi pre']
```